# How do you set file permissions in Lion?

Tags: macos, permission

I just loaded Lion on my Mac and now cannot access certain files. How can I change the permissions of a certain file?

I've tried to find the HD in Finder but it doesn't show up.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way of setting permission to a file is:

1. Select the file you want to change permissions to.
2. Hit <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>.
3. In the last part of the *information panel*, just authenticate and change the permissions as you want them.

This can be achieved, too, through terminal with the **chmod** command.

Lion does not show the HD by default. In the **General** tab of the Finder's preferences just check **Show this items on Desktop: Hard Drive**, and it will be shown. You can also type <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to open a Finder window for the whole drive directly.